# Same table, two statements, need the difference between the two

Tags: sql, difference

I am an English major stumbling my way around very basic SQL Stuff. I have gotten the follwing two statements to return the results I need (both from the same table):

```
select *
from Table1
where Column1 = 'Examplel' and UniqueID is not null
order by UniqueID2
```

> *(2000 lines returned)*

```
select *
from Table1
where Column1 = 'Examplel'
and ColumnDATE between '2008-02-12 00:00:00.000' and '2013-08-15 00:00:00.000'
order by UniqueID2
```

> *(2001 lines returned)*

I need to find that one line of difference, prefereably without scrolling and comparing all lines in both results. Help?

Comment: Try: `second_query minus first_query` (remove the "order by" it's not necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Run this all as one statement:

```
select * from Table1 where Column1 = 'Examplel' and UniqueID is not null order by UniqueID2

except

select * from Table1 where Column1 = 'Examplel' and ColumnDATE between '2008-02-12 00:00:00.000' and '2013-08-15 00:00:00.000' order by UniqueID2
```

Then run the reverse:

```
select * from Table1 where Column1 = 'Examplel' and ColumnDATE between '2008-02-12 00:00:00.000' and '2013-08-15 00:00:00.000' order by UniqueID2

except

select * from Table1 where Column1 = 'Examplel' and UniqueID is not null order by UniqueID2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from Table1
where Column1 = 'Examplel'
and ColumnDATE between '2008-02-12 00:00:00.000' and '2013-08-15 00:00:00.000
and UniqueID is null
order by UniqueID2
```

Comment: +1 yes, that should work too :) (and much more efficient than my proposed solution above)

Comment: So from the count we know there is one diff record, but the thing to consider is you can have two more "diff" records, one of each in each query, that don't show in the count.  One with UniqueId=5, ColumnDate=2000-02-12, and another with UniqueId=null, ColumnDate=2012-01-01.  Each is in one of the queries and thus are diff's, but the former will not show up in this query.  Perhaps not an issue for you, but something to consider.

Comment: Yes, I've considered that.